My Gatsby / Netlify form isn't submitting any form data
When a form is submitted on the website, the submission appears in Netlify Forms, but the contents is empty.
Here's the form code:
    <form className="mt-4" method="POST" netlify netlify-honeypot="bot-field" data-netlify="true" name="form-name">
      <input type="hidden" name="bot-field" />
      <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="form-name" />
      <div className="mb-6">
        <label className="block text-gray-700 text-lg mb-1" htmlFor="name">
          Your Name
        </label>
        <input className="rounded-md appearance-none w-full py-4 px-4 text-gray-700focus:outline-none" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" required />
      </div>
      <div className="mb-6">
        <label className="block text-gray-700 text-lg mb-1" htmlFor="email">
          Your Email
        </label>
        <input className="rounded-md appearance-none w-full py-4 px-4 text-gray-700focus:outline-none" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email" required />
      </div>
      <div className="mb-6">
        <label className="block text-gray-700 text-lg mb-1" htmlFor="email">
          Your form-name
        </label>
        <textarea rows="10" className="rounded-md appearance-none w-full py-4 px-4 text-gray-700focus:outline-none" id="form-name" placeholder="Your enquiry" required />
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
        <button className="bg-gray-800 block w-full md:inline-block md:w-auto hover:bg-gray-600 text-white font-bold py-5 px-8 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>

Here's The URL:
https://party-pix.co.uk/
